# QUERY, FILTER or lookup for two conditions in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, lookup

I'd like to create a column of simple formulae in the Holdings! tab of this [Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FwyqZScGtUwGHlQa72av3s4c3HvfvO5bTdFjvxUe4Zs/edit?usp=sharing) to do the following:

1. Look in Holdings!A for a company name
2. Look in Holdings!D for the date of the company's most recent round (ie the highest date)
3. Return the holding value in Rounds!C that matches both the company name from Rounds!A and the highest date in Rounds!B

I've tried to do it with QUERY, FILTER, INDEX and MATCH and looked at quite a lot of stuff on SO and Google product forums.

The general problem is to do a lookup-type function based on matching both of two conditions where I want an exact match with the first text condition and the maximum number (ie date) on the second condition,

Comment: Please add what you tried - and how that failed!

Answer (score 0):

Try any of the following formula in cell F2:

```
=filter(Rounds!C:C,Rounds!A:A=A2,Rounds!B:B=max(filter(Rounds!B:B,Rounds!A:A=A2)))
```

```
=+query(Rounds!A:C,"select C where A='"&A2&"' order by B desc",0)
```

and then drag it to the cells below it.